# Multipe server in grpc

Tags: go, grpc, rpc

Is it possible to have multiple servers in gRPC and choose from them dynamically?

I'm looking for a solution that connects a central server to several servers on the Internet and detects which server to run the received task dynamically

Comment: Multiple instances of the same server, or multiple different servers on a single or multiple hosts? The answer is "yes" broadly, but you need to be more specific to figure out what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the central server a proxy, and forward requests to the real servers.

If the services are the same, the proxy can do roundrobin, or other algorithms, and it basically becomes a load balancer.

If the services are different, the proxy can forward based on host name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), or based on the RPC service+method.

Comment: I'm thinking about websocket or net tcp options